# Django channels times out with daphne and worker

Tags: django, worker, django-channels, daphne

I have a problem with django channels.
My Django app was running perfectly with WSGI for HTTP requests.
I tried to migrate to channels in order to allow websocket requests, and it turns out that after installing channels and running ASGI (daphne) and a worker, the server answers error 503 and the browser displays error 504 (time out) for the http requests that were previously working (admin page for example).
I read all the tutorial I could find and I do not see what the problem can be. Moreover, if I run with "runserver", it works fine.

I have an Nginx in front of the app (on a separate server), working as proxy and loadbalancer.
I use Django 1.9.5 with asgi-redis>=0.10.0, channels>=0.17.0 and daphne>=0.15.0. The wsgi.py and asgi.py files are in the same folder. Redis is working.

The command I was previously using with WSGI (and which still works if I switch back to it) is:
`uwsgi --http :8000 --master --enable-threads --module Cats.wsgi`

The command that works using runserver is:
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

The commands that fail for the requests that work with the 2 other commands are:
`daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 Cats.asgi:channel_layer 
python manage.py runworker`

Other info:
I added 'channels' in the installed apps (in settings.py)

other settings.py relevant info

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
"default": {
    "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
    "ROUTING": "Cats.routing.app_routing",
    "CONFIG": {
        "hosts": [(os.environ['REDIS_HOST'], 6379)],
    },
},
```

}

Cats/routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route, include
from main.routing import routing as main_routing

app_routing = [
    include(main_routing, path=r"^/ws/main"),
]
```

main/routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route, include

http_routing = [
]

stream_routing = [
    route('websocket.receive', 'main.consumers.ws_echo'), #just for test once it will work
]

routing = [
    include(stream_routing),
    include(http_routing),
]
```

main/consumers.py

```
def ws_echo(message):
message.reply_channel.send({
    'text': message.content['text'],
})

#this consumer is just for test once it will work
```

Any idea what could be wrong? All help much appreciated! Ty

EDIT:
I tried a new thing:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noworker
python manage.py runworker
```

And this does not work, while `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` was working...

Any idea that could help?

Comment: Edited my post with a new attempt to separate the worker from the "runserver". It fails too

Comment: Have you checked redis if daphne actually puts the request onto the queue?

Comment: Did you solve this in the meantime? We have channels running in production but when I try and deploy the same project on our dev server I get this problem. The worker receives the request but it stops there. daphne (runserver) returns a 503 and in the browser I get 504.

Comment: well, solution was simple... only had forgotten a &: python manage.py runworker & python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 --noworker

Answer (score 2):

channels will use default views for un-routed requests.
assuming you use the javascripts right, I suggest you use only your default Cats/routing.py file as following:

```
from channels.routing import route
from main.consumers import *


app_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_echo, path="/ws/main")
]
```

or with reverse to help with your path

```
from django.urls import reverse

from channels.routing import route
from main.consumers import *


app_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', ws_echo, path=reverse('main view name'))
]
```

I think also your consumer should be changed. when browser connects using websockets the server should first handle adding message reply channel. something like:

```
def ws_echo(message):
    Group("notifications").add(message.reply_channel)
    Group("notifications").send({
        "text": json.dumps({'testkey':'testvalue'})
    })
```

the send function should probably be called up on different event and the "notifications" Group should probably changed to have a channel dedicated to the user. something like

```
from channels.auth import channel_session_user_from_http

@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_echo(message):
    Group("notify-private-%s" % message.user.id).add(message.reply_channel)
    Group("notify-private-%s" % message.user.id).send({
        "text": json.dumps({'testkey':'testvalue'})
    })
```

Comment: dedicated to the user is much simpler: `message.reply_channel.send({'text':json.dumps({'test':'tetest'})})`
unless you expect the user to have multiple connections that all need the message.

Comment: indeed message.reply_channel.send can work but I think multiple tabs is a legit usage of webapps hence multi connections

Answer (score 1):

If you're using heroku or dokku make sure you've properly set the "scale" to include the worker process. By default they will only run the web instance and not the worker!

For heroku

```
heroku ps:scale web=1:free worker=1:free
```

For dokku create a file named `DOKKU_SCALE` and add in:

```
web=1
worker=1
```

See:

- http://blog.codelv.com/2017/10/timouts-django-channels-on-dokku.html
- https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django